# getStateByRange() returning empty iterator for in Hyperledger Fabric Java SDK

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I am trying to get all entries in the ledger (Fabric 1.4.4, using Java Chaincode):

```
QueryResultsIterator<KeyValue> iterator = ctx.getStub().getStateByRange("","");
```

But I always get an empty iterator. Is this the correct way to get all entries?

(At least a way to get all keys would work for me as then I can get states one by one, but for that I need all keys)

Comment: This looks like the correct way. Just have a look at [this](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/master/chaincode/fabcar/java/src/main/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/samples/fabcar/FabCar.java#L152) example, just in case you are missing something while iterating. One other possible approach that you can take can be, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59201642/8308259) by just changing the event payload with the key that you are putting into the world state.

Comment: I will check those links, thanks. The problem is that I don't have any key. SmartContract has a method that needs to iterate through all values stored to perform a checksum and return it, so I need to get all entries (or get all keys and iterate one by one, that would do the trick)

Comment: yes, and that method is getStateByRange, which should probably work, but is somehow not working, do have a look at these links and let me know if they helped.

Comment: I added a reply: getStateByRange("A","Z") is working for me but may not fit everyone. I think getStateByRange("","") definitely is not working or else my workaround should not work either.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I now can think of one more possible way, can you please try and confirm about this, whether supplying startIndex as "" and endIndex as "~" works?

Comment: icordoba @UdyanSharma have you found something that works?

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff nothing from my end on the same. Maybe icordoba has something for us.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason getStateByRange("","") is not working in Fabric Java SDK but this will work:

```
getStateByRange("A","Z")
```

(all my ids start with a capital letters so I get all entries with that)

Comment: It seems that getStateByRange isn't fixed at this day, because doesn't work for me either. This is very upsetting.

Comment: getStateByRange isn't working for me, no matter what strings I use!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you a lot for the strange solution, but it helps me really.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `getStateByRange` can't return states stored using composite keys

if you use directly :

```
await ctx.stub.putState('objName', Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

it will work

but if you use a composite key like

```
   let key = ctx.stub.createCompositeKey("objName", [obj]);
   await ctx.stub.putState('objName', Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(obj)));
```

it will return an empty response.

The cause is that `getStateByRange` uses a null delimiter `\u0000` delimiting the key parts and then the stored states would not be returned (e.g  `{"Key":"\u0000objName\u0000obj1\u0000","Record":"\u0000"}` ).
To read the states when a composite key is used you'll need to use `getStateByPartialCompositeKey`

Comment: ``getStateByPartialCompositeKey`` works like a charm with composite keys. I wonder why documentation says nothing about the fact that ``getStateByRange`` will not work with composite keys. Also to me remains unclear the reason why ``getStateByRange`` do not support ``ChaincodeStub.createCompositeKey(String key)`` as a search pattern

Answer (score -3):

I am not sure that returning the entire blockchain is a good idea.

Anyways, you could get the history for a single key by using

```
APIstub.GetHistoryForKey(id)
```

This will return all the transaction involved for that particular id

Comment: Thanks but I do need to get all states (not really all the blockchain but at least all the keys). GetHistoryForKey(id) won't work as maybe I don't know the id to ask for.