# How to get the parameters passed to the transaction for the historical states

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am trying to get the operation which is responsible for the new state. In simple words, I want to get the function name passed to the invoke method. When I am looking into the historical states I am able to fetch its value, timestamp, transaction ID, etc. but not the parameters which are responsible for that transaction.

I know we can get the parameters from the block history, but I need it for the states.

Is there any way to achieve this from the chaincode side?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, from the chaincode you can create an Invoke endpoint and do like:

```
func (s *SmartContract) Invoke(APIstub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface) sc.Response {
function, args := APIstub.GetFunctionAndParameters()
}
```

Here you got everything you want.
For example if you print **function** you will see the name of the function you invoked.

Comment: Please check the question, I need the function name for historical states

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know about your approach as well. However this would be my take on this,we can probably register an event listener in our sdk (using ***registerChaincodeEvent*** method) and create an Event (using ***setEvent*** method) in our chaincode ,wherein our payload would be the result from ***getFunctionAndParameters*** method. And you can probably keep storing these results into a datastore to later fetch them all.

**Alternatively:** You can simply send back the result of ***getFunctionAndParameters*** as a key in the response object via shim.success.

Comment: This is my approach:
1) We'll get the transaction ID for the state change
2) Find the block with the transaction
3) Get the parameters from the block

Comment: For step 1, if I am not wrong you might have registered an event for each transaction, based on a tx_id using the registerTxEvent ? If yes, then you can possibly try the approach I suggested for chaincode Events

Comment: No, I am getting the txID from the state itself

Comment: If I am not wrong, then you are probably using the getHistoryForKey. Then [https://godoc.org/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-protos-go/ledger/queryresult#KeyModification](this) is the response proto for each object in the iterator, and hence I think there is no way you can get it from that API and IMHO I think chaincode event is your way to achieve this.